# Unable to center <ul> inside of navbar with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to center `<ul>` inside of navbar `<div>` with `margin: 0 auto;` property but it's not working. I've found dozens solutions for it but none of them worked...
This list has to be vertical.

HTML:

```
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <% link_to '', root_path, id: 'logo' %>
    <a id="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a>
    <div id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#speciality">Our speciality</a></li>
        <li><a href="#team">Our team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#workflow">How do we do it</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
  width: 100%;

  .container {
    width: 100%;

    #navigation {
      //display: none;
      height: auto;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
      width: 100%;

      ul {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;

        li {
          clear: both;
          display: inline-block;
          padding: 15px;

          a {
            color: $c-text-white;
            font: $font-family-base;
            font-size: 20px;
            text-transform: uppercase;

            &:hover {
              color: $c-text-orange;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

**Solution:**

Bootstrap `navbar-nav` class was somehow overwriting my css. So removing it and using code from [Paulie_D's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30277844/4169845) fixed the problem

Comment: Your CSS is nested...

Comment: @odedta That looks like SCSS...a pre-processor language.

Comment: @odedta It's scss. It doesn't work in scss?

Comment: Roger that, I don't know SCSS so I can't help you there. :/

Comment: @odedta No problem :) You should try it. It's pretty convenient!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ul` are block level and so 100% wide by default.

If you make it `inline-block` and apply `text-align:center'`to the parent you should get what you want.

```
 #navigation {
        height: auto;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        ul {
            text-align: center;
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/fat4mdvm/)

Comment: it works without `<header>` and `<div class="container">` wrapping `#navigation`. But even if I remove those tags and copy the code from your fiddle it still doesn't work. Maybe the problem is bootstrap? Maybe it overwrites css somehow?

Comment: Quite possible. If you found this answer helpful, feel free to upvote

Comment: Thank you! It was helpful. But unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to upvote. As soon as I get 15 of it I will certainly do that :)